# How to prevent scrolling the document upper than a div position using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

My homepage display a full windows image.

On click the page scrolls a full page down .

I like then to block the possibility to scroll up again higher than

```
     <div id="header-logo">
```

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: You mean you want to simply block the client from scrolling up at all ?after a certain height ?

Comment: well i dont think there's a way to simply block it completely. however what you can do, is make a check if scroll to a certain height set a flag to true, then another check if user ever scrolled bellow that height,  then scroll the window to the height you wanted.

Comment: Personally, I'd just wrap whatever is above `<div id="header-logo">` and then add `display: none` style to that element.

Comment: there you go that's another option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:

I'd just wrap whatever is above `<div id="header-logo">` and then hide that element. The fiddle I created below uses a css transition to smoothly minimize the area you don't want to be able to scroll back to. Then after the transition, scroll to the area you want to move to.

```
 $('#clicky').click(function(){
     $('#topPart').css('height', '0px');
     setTimeout(function(){
         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#stuffBelow').offset().top}, '1500' );
     }, 510); //10ms more than transition (sometimes scrolls too far otherwise)
 });
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baacke/G69ac/).